# Unable to get Fluidbox 1.4.2 working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I suspect that I'm missing something stupid because this almost (but not quite) works. The images that should be showing up in the lighbox load, but do display. The Fluidbox demo in the main web site works as expected, but I can't seem to get this working as a minimal example even using the same JS and CSS links as in the example page.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Fluidbox Test</h1>
        <p>A bit of para text before the images</p>
        <div id="SomeRow" class="SomeClass">
            <!-- images display, but clicking on the images does not display the larger images, though lightbox does show with empty content -->
            <!-- large images load on request - you can see that in Firebug - but they never display in the light box -->
            <a href="http://dragoons.info/photos/2008 Season/New Haven/00140.jpg" title="00140.jpg" data-fluidbox=""><img src="http://dragoons.info/photos/2008 Season/New Haven/Thumbs/00140.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="http://dragoons.info/photos/2008 Season/New Haven/00144.jpg" title="00144.jpg" data-fluidbox=""><img src="http://dragoons.info/photos/2008 Season/New Haven/Thumbs/00144.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="http://dragoons.info/photos/2008 Season/New Haven/00149.jpg" title="00149.jpg" data-fluidbox=""><img src="http://dragoons.info/photos/2008 Season/New Haven/Thumbs/00149.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <p>A bit text after the images</p>

        <!-- script and CSS links are same as used by Fluidbox web site, so this should work, in theory -->
        <!-- http://terrymun.github.io/Fluidbox/?utm_source=jquer.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation -->
        <!-- Fluidbox works fine there, but does not display images when when clicked in this example -->

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Fluidbox -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://terrymun.github.io/Fluidbox/jquery.fluidbox.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://terrymun.github.io/Fluidbox/css/fluidbox.css" media="all" />

        <script>
            //start the show
            $(window).load(function () {
                $("a").fluidbox(); //images adjusted to Fluidbox format in generated HTML, so this part works 
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing? The code runs without error. I can see a successful image load request via Firebug, but the image is never added to the "fluidbox-ghost" element via "background-image" as it is in the Fluidbox demo page. Using FireFox 33.1 and Safari 5.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. Fluidbox does not work correctly with spaces in the image links. Replace the spaces in the URLs with "%20" and everything works as expected.